# Comunicação com baudrate 110

Tags: c, linux, arduino, serial

Tenho que receber dados de um equipamento que tem uma interface TTL que manda os dados a 110 bits por segundos.

Em todos os testes que realizei quando tento chegar a essa velocidade tenho problemas, por exemplo:

- Meu programa não recebe os 9 bytes enviados, somente 8 e o que recebe
  não condiz com que deveria.
- Receber Usando o minicom (Linux Ubuntu) ele não aceita configurar o baudrate com 110 somente 300 o que não favorece na leitura.
- Com Arduino (ide v1.6 e v1.8) quando mando alguma coisa pela serial a 300 bits por segundo só vai caracteres sem sentido, qualquer outra velocidade funciona (to mandando um simples Serial.println("oi") )

Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Talvez você tenha uma hance melhor de alguém saber responder se perguntar aqui: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ - já que essa dúvida não vai se resolver com conhecimento ou entendimento de algoritmos, e sim, configuração da porta serial, e possivelmente de componentes físicos do link.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é utilizar a linguagem Python usando o módulo pyserial. É um módulo bem versátil, podendo receber diversas configurações da comunicação serial e padrões.

Um exemplo de código em Python usando serial abaixo:

```
import serial

class Comunicacao():

    def SerialInit(self, NomePorta, Velocidade, TimeRX, TimeTX):

        try:
            self.PortaCom = serial.Serial(NomePorta, Velocidade, 8, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE, TimeRX,
                                          False, False, False, TimeTX)
            self.PortaCom.reset_input_buffer()
            self.PortaCom.reset_output_buffer()

        except Exception:
            print("Erro na porta " + NomePorta + "!")



    def WriteSerial(self, DadosTx):

        try:
            self.PortaCom.flushOutput()
            TamPac = DadosTx[3]
            for i in range(TamPac):
                DadoTxByte = bytes((DadosTx[i],))

                self.PortaCom.write(DadoTxByte)
                print(DadoTxByte)

        except Exception:
            print("Erro Escrita")

    def Leitura_Serial(self, DadosRx):

        LeituraSerial = [0] * 200

        for i in range(200):

            if (self.PortaCom.in_waiting > 0):
                LeituraSerial[i] = self.PortaCom.read()
                LeituraSerial[i] = self.ByteToInt(LeituraSerial[i])
                print(LeituraSerial[i])

            else:
                break

DadosTx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
DadosRx = [0] * 100
PortaCom = Comunicacao()
PortaCom.SerialInit("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, 1, 1)
PortaCom.WriteSerial(DadosRx)
```

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer leitura com o Python e tive o o mesmo problema, seria possível que no Kernel da Raspberry a UART esteja limitada a trabalhar a 300 bps?

Digo isso porque essa é a menor velocidade que consigo conectar com o minicom.